# How do I install 64 bit Vim for python development on Windows?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, vim

I want to install 64 bit Vim to work with 64 python on windows because my machine is 64 bit and I want to work with Tensorflow, which only works with 64 bit python. However, I can't for the life of me find a way to install a 64 bit version of Vim to work with a 64 bit version of python. Every time I manage to install it (gVim) I am greeted with:

`E370: Could not load library python35.dll`

`E263: Sorry, this command is disabled, the Python library could not be loaded`

after entering any python command to Vim e.g. `:python3 print('Hello')`

Is it possible or a thing people do using Vim with 64 bit python? If not, what text editor should I be using? If so, please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the 64-bit portable version of gVim 8.0 running on Windows 8 with 64 bit Python v3.6.1. I unzipped the portable version of gVim from the zip file:

```
gvim_8.0.1427_x64.zip
```

Without modifying the install I ran the command

```
:python3 print('Hello')
```

and received a reassuring 'Hello' in the editor window.

I have not tried the installable version of gVim. Perhaps the portable version works more easily?

Comment: Hi, yes I actually figured this out on my own this morning, but I happened to do what you said plus I needed to add the location of the python36.dll file to my PATH environmental variable and it worked saying Hello right back at me! Thanks for the help